# Matching or regular expression in scala

Tags: regex, scala, switch-statement, pattern-matching, regex-group

I have a regular expression like `".*(A20).*|.*(B30).*|C"`.
I would like to write a function its returns `A20` or `B30` based on the match found.

```
val regx=".*(A20).*|.*(B30).*".r

"helloA20" match { case regx(b,_) => b; case _ => "" } // A20
"helloB30" match { case regx(b,_) => b; case _ => "" } // null
 "C" match { case regx(b,_) => b case _ => "" }
```

It's returning null because I am not considering the second group. In my actual code, I have a lot of group like that. I would like to return the matched string. Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: I thin all you need is `.*(A20|B30).*`. Do you need the whole string, or the captured value too? If you do not need the captured value, just use `.*(?:A20|B30).*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks.My regex would have different or(|) condition with different logic like ".*(A20).*|(B30)|(C)".I need the captured value for further processing like A20,B30,C

Comment: Then give us the full example so we can hep you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close:

```
def extract(s: String) = s match {
 case regx(b, _) if b != null => b
 case regx(_, b) if b != null => b
 case _ => "" 
}

extract("helloA20")
res3: String = A20

extract("helloB30")
res4: String = B30

extract("A30&B30")
res6: String = B30
```

If you have a lot of groups, it's reasonable to use for comprehension insted of pattern matching. This code will return first match or None:

```
val letters = ('A' to 'Z').toSeq
val regex = letters.map(_.toString).mkString("(", "|", ")").r

def extract(s: String) = {
  for {
    m <- regex.findFirstMatchIn(s)
  } yield m.group(1)
}

extract("A=B=")
extract("dsfdsBA")
extract("C====b")
extract("a====E")

res0: Option[String] = Some(A)
res1: Option[String] = Some(B)
res2: Option[String] = Some(C)
res3: Option[String] = Some(E)
```

Comment: @vitailykotlyarenko thanks. Your solution is working perfectly fine. But I have couple of groups like this.Do I have to write case statement for each group or is there any better solution than this.

Comment: @vitailykotlyarenko,Thanks its working fine. Some of the cases like extract("===B")( if a match found and index > 1) I am getting an array index out of bound exception.I think we are matching the position index with group index.I tried to change into m.group(1) since we have only one group and now its not throwing any exception.Please advice me if anything wrong in using m.group(1).

Comment: You're right, m.group(1) is correct. I wrote my code at Sunday night, not the best time for coding ). Check my last edit, it became even simpler after the fix.

Answer (score 3):

Easy! It should be like this:

```
val regx="^(.*(B30|A20).*|(C))$".r
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nA6dQ9/1

Then you get the second value in the array of every group.
[image: This is what I mean!]

That way you only have one group regardless of the many possibilities.

Comment: sorry if i am not clear with the question,  .* is not common for the entire  pattern. I am dealing with pattern like this                  .*(A20).*|(B30)|(C)" . In B30 and C it should not have starts with any other strings.I will update my question. @aminahnuraini